# Regex in Javascript - Need to allow decimal as first character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a React widget that lets you type in a price.  I put the typed-in text through a regex.test() to ensure only numbers and 1 decimal are allowed in the number.  However, the regex I'm using doesn't allow a decimal point as the first character (e.g. -> .05).  My current regex is

```
`/^(\d+\.?\d{0,9}|\.\d{1,9})$/`
```

I tried adding an optional `\.?` in the front of this, but it didn't work.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried this `RegExp('^(\\d+\\.?\\d{0,9}|\\.\\d{1,9})$')`?

Comment: That regex doesn't allow any text to pass

Comment: Are you sure it does not? See https://regex101.com/r/KOs9G7/1. I'd write your regex as `/^(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,9})?|\.\d{1,9})$/` though

Comment: Double-checking...maybe my React component is filtering out 0 values

Comment: Yeah, my React component was filtering out zero values, which "." evaluates to.  I've adjusted your regex to /^(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,9})$/   (replaced the 9 with the 2) to limit the decimals to 2 spots, but it doesn't work if the first character is a ".".  It does work if the first character is a digit.

Comment: And to the person who gave this question a down vote, if questions like this don't belong on Stack Overflow, what does??

Comment: @bluedevil2k do you want to allow integers or just float only

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/^\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

```js
const testFunc = (str) =>{
  return str.length > 0 && /^\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(str)
}

console.log(testFunc(''))
console.log(testFunc('.123'))
console.log(testFunc('1'))
console.log(testFunc('1.123'))
console.log(testFunc('123.123.123'))
```